# SQL Server Agent Jobs Log custom warning in Job History

Tags: sql-server, logging

I know about the opportunity to log custom messages from SQL Server Agent job in the job history messages (print, raiserror).

I was wondering if it also is possible to create warnings?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RAISEERROR/THROW` with **[severity level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx)** from 0-9.

> Informational messages that return status information or report errors
>   that are not severe. The Database Engine does not raise system errors
>   with severities of 0 through 9.

and:

> Errors with severity from 0 through 10 are informational messages and
>   do not cause execution to jump from the CATCH block of a TRY…CATCH
>   construct.

Comment: Thanks answering. But it does not help. I try to execute a job with one steps. Inside i have several try...catch-blocks. if one catch is reached the whole step stops (if i use e.g. severity level 9) or it continues with the next step - BUT then the job executes as "Ok" (green). I am looking for a "warning" (symbol), so i can see "Ah something is wrong, But continue with the next steps" :)

Comment: @Frank Try `RAISEERROR ... WITH LOG`

Comment: Sorry, but no effekt.